# How to process class **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, class, arguments, self, keyword-argument

How could I set object attributes using "one" class argument `**kwargs`?

The thing I want is to do this code in one loop:

```
class purchase():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.set_attributes(kwargs)

    def set_attributes(self,kwargs):
        if 'file' in kwargs.keys():
            self.file = kwargs['file']
        if 'text' in kwargs.keys():
            self.text = kwargs['text']
        if 'language' in kwargs.keys():
            self.language = kwargs['language']
```

It should be something like:

```
class purchase():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.set_attributes(kwargs)

    def set_attributes(self,kwargs):
        for v,k in kwargs.iteritems():
            self.k = v
```

which of course does not work.

Is there a way how to programatically set object attributes in one loop?

Comment: You are looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: or `vars(self).update(kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
class purchase():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.set_attributes(kwargs)

    def set_attributes(self,kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```